# How to program a ProgressBar in C# in WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

It's my first time to use [`ProgressBar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx)s in WindowsForms and I have a specific float variable that changes repeatedly that I want to display in the `ProgressBar` any idea how to do it ?

These are the six variables that I need to display on progress bars:

```
  float[] emo = new float[6];
  emo[0] = face.Emotions.Fear;
  emo[1] = face.Emotions.Anger;
  emo[2] = face.Emotions.Surprise;
  emo[3] = face.Emotions.Joy;
  emo[4] = face.Emotions.Sadness;
  emo[5] = face.Emotions.Disgust;


 //progressBar1.Increment(face.Emotions.Fear);
```

Comment: just to clarify, you want to display the emoticons in the progressbar? as in an image of an emoticon?

Comment: no, its just a float variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to set the `Value` property of the `ProgressBar` to the variable you want to display. Value is an `int` property so you would have to convert from `float` to `int`.